# Scraping stats with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping

I would to scrape 1st half result and minute of goals in 2nd half from this page https://www.flashscore.co.uk/match/dxm5iiWh/#match-summary

Then I tried to scrape 1st half stats from this page https://www.flashscore.co.uk/match/dxm5iiWh/#match-statistics;1
with this code but I would fix Xpaths

P.S In the example I put only two stats but I will apply for all.

Thanks

```py
stats=[]
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.co.uk/match/dxm5iiWh/#match-summary')

data = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "utime"))).text
hometeam=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='flashscore']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/a"))).text
awayteam=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='flashscore']/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/a"))).text

md = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("detailMS__incidentRow")

for g in md:
    if g.find_elements_by_class_name("icon.soccer-ball"):
        print(g.text)


try:
    extrainfo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='flashscore']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]").text
except NoSuchElementException:
    extrainfo = " "
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='a-match-statistics']")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='a-match-statistics']"))).click()   
    home_shot=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tab-statistics-0-statistic']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]"))).text
    away_shot=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tab-statistics-0-statistic']/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]"))).text
    home_shotontarget=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tab-statistics-0-statistic']/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]"))).text
    away_shotontarget=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tab-statistics-0-statistic']/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]"))).text
except NoSuchElementException:
    home_shot = "no stats"
    away_shot = "no stats"
    home_shotontarget = "no stats"
    away_shotontarget = "no stats"

    stats.append((data, hometeam, awayteam, print(g.text), extrainfo, home_shot, away_shot, home_shotontarget, away_shotontarget))

    df = pd.DataFrame(stats, columns=['data', 'hometeam', 'awayteam', 'goals', 
'extrainfo', 'hs', 'as', 'hot', 'aot'])
    df.to_csv('stats.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: please add [mwe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self%2Dcontained%20correct%20example.)

Comment: what is the output?What is the expected output?

Comment: I expect to have all stats from home team and away team

Comment: and what is the problem ? Do you get error message ? Do you need better xpath? Why not use `statText statText--homeValue` and `statText statText--awayValue`? It would be simpler if you would create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run - to see problems and test ideas.

Comment: That is my full code, I need a better xpath that is good for all stats. And I need to put minutes of goals in columns.

Comment: For cicle scrape all info but I need only the minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
             
import pandas as pd
             

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

stats = []

# go to page with match summary 
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.co.uk/match/dxm5iiWh/#match-summary')

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
data = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "utime"))).text
hometeam = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='flashscore']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/a"))).text
awayteam = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='flashscore']/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/a"))).text

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#match_details = driver.find_element_by_class_name("detailMS__incidentRow")

match_details = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"incidentRow--home")] | //div[contains(@class, "incidentRow--away")]')

print(' {:4} | {:4} | {:5} | {:17} | {:17} | {:17} |'.format('h/a', 'time', 'icon', 'participant', 'substitution_in', 'substitution_out'))

for row in match_details:
     home_or_away = row.get_attribute('class')
     home_or_away = 'home' if 'home' in home_or_away else 'away'
     #print('home_or_away:', home_or_away)
     
     time_box = row.find_element_by_class_name('time-box').text.strip()
     icon     = row.find_element_by_class_name('icon').get_attribute('class').replace('icon ', '')
     
     try:
         participant_name = row.find_element_by_class_name('participant-name').text.strip()
     except:
         participant_name = ''
         
     try:
         substitution_in_name = row.find_element_by_class_name('substitution-in-name').text.strip()
     except:
         substitution_in_name = ''
         
     try:
         substitution_out_name = row.find_element_by_class_name('substitution-out-name').text.strip()
     except:
         substitution_out_name = ''
         
     print(' {:4} | {:4} | {:5} | {:17} | {:17} | {:17} |'.format(home_or_away, time_box, icon, participant_name, substitution_in_name, substitution_out_name))

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

try:
    extrainfo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='flashscore']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]").text
except NoSuchElementException:
    extrainfo = " "
    
print('extrainfo:', extrainfo)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# go to page with stats
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='a-match-statistics']")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='a-match-statistics']"))).click()   

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# get stats 
for row in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="tab-statistics-0-statistic"]//div[@class="statTextGroup"]'):
    columns = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
    columns = [x.text.strip() for x in columns]
    print('{:17} | {:>3} | {:>3} |'.format(columns[1], columns[0], columns[2]))

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#stats.append((data, hometeam, awayteam, print(g.text), extrainfo, home_shot, away_shot, home_shotontarget, away_shotontarget))

#df = pd.DataFrame(stats, columns=['data', 'hometeam', 'awayteam', 'goals', 'extrainfo', 'hs', 'as', 'hot', 'aot'])
#df.to_csv('stats.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Result:

```
 h/a  | time | icon            | participant       | substitution_in   | substitution_out  |
 home | 59'  | y-card          | Dunk L.           |                   |                   |
 home | 65'  | y-card          | Jahanbakhsh A.    |                   |                   |
 away | 66'  | substitution-in |                   | Lacazette A.      | Martinelli        |
 away | 66'  | soccer-ball     | Lacazette A.      |                   |                   |
 home | 67'  | substitution-in |                   | Maupay N.         | Mac Allister A.   |
 home | 68'  | substitution-in |                   | March S.          | Propper D.        |
 home | 75'  | substitution-in |                   | Trossard L.       | Jahanbakhsh A.    |
 away | 81'  | substitution-in |                   | Ceballos D.       | Saka B.           |
 away | 89'  | substitution-in |                   | Maitland-Niles A. | Smith Rowe E.     |
extrainfo: Finished
Ball possession   | 50% | 50% |
Goal attempts     |  13 |  11 |
Shots on goal     |   2 |   3 |
Shots off goal    |   5 |   6 |
Blocked Shots     |   6 |   2 |
Free kicks        |   4 |  11 |
Corner kicks      |   5 |   4 |
Offsides          |   0 |   0 |
Goalkeeper saves  |   2 |   2 |
Fouls             |  11 |   4 |
Yellow cards      |   2 |   0 |
Total Passes      | 491 | 511 |
Tackles           |  17 |  10 |
Attacks           | 116 | 108 |
Dangerous Attacks |  58 |  34 |
```

Now you have to figure out how to organize in table `DataFrame`.
Times with indcidents doesn't fit me to table but rather in separed table in SQL database which is related with match details.

---

**EDIT**:

Code which add every information in separated column. For stats it is OK but for incidents (goals, substitutions, yellow card) it makes a lot of columns and every match will have different number of columns so it will be hard to compare values. How to compare goals when one match will have goal in columns 1,2 but other in columns 6,9. I would rather keep it database - one incident in one row - and use query with `WHERE incident = goal`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
             
import pandas as pd
             

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

stats = []

# go to page with match summary 
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.co.uk/match/dxm5iiWh/#match-summary')

stats_row = {}
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

stats_row['data']     = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "utime"))).text
stats_row['hometeam'] = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='flashscore']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/a"))).text
stats_row['awayteam'] = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='flashscore']/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/a"))).text

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#match_details = driver.find_element_by_class_name("detailMS__incidentRow")

match_details = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"incidentRow--home")] | //div[contains(@class, "incidentRow--away")]')

print(' {:4} | {:4} | {:15} | {:17} | {:17} | {:17} |'.format('h/a', 'time', 'icon', 'participant', 'substitution_in', 'substitution_out'))
print(' {:4} | {:4} | {:15} | {:17} | {:17} | {:17} |'.format('-'*4, '-'*4, '-'*15, '-'*17, '-'*17, '-'*17))

for number, row in enumerate(match_details, 1):
     home_or_away = row.get_attribute('class')
     home_or_away = 'home' if 'home' in home_or_away else 'away'
     stats_row['home_or_away'] = home_or_away
     #print('home_or_away:', home_or_away)
     
     time_box = row.find_element_by_class_name('time-box').text.strip()
     icon     = row.find_element_by_class_name('icon').get_attribute('class').replace('icon ', '')
     
     try:
         participant_name = row.find_element_by_class_name('participant-name').text.strip()
     except:
         participant_name = ''
         
     try:
         substitution_in_name = row.find_element_by_class_name('substitution-in-name').text.strip()
     except:
         substitution_in_name = ''
         
     try:
         substitution_out_name = row.find_element_by_class_name('substitution-out-name').text.strip()
     except:
         substitution_out_name = ''
         
     print(' {:4} | {:4} | {:15} | {:17} | {:17} | {:17} |'.format(home_or_away, time_box, icon, participant_name, substitution_in_name, substitution_out_name))

     #stats_row['incident - {} '.format(number)] = [home_or_away, time_box, icon, participant_name, substitution_in_name, substitution_out_name]
   
     stats_row['incident - {} - home_or_away'.format(number)] = home_or_away
     stats_row['incident - {} - time_box'.format(number)] = time_box
     stats_row['incident - {} - icon'.format(number)] = icon
     stats_row['incident - {} - participant_name'.format(number)] = participant_name
     stats_row['incident - {} - substitution_in_name'.format(number)] = substitution_in_name
     stats_row['incident - {} - substitution_out_name'.format(number)] = substitution_out_name
     
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

try:
    stats_row['extrainfo'] = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='flashscore']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]").text
except NoSuchElementException:
    stats_row['extrainfo'] = ""
    
print('extrainfo:', stats_row['extrainfo'])

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# go to page with stats
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='a-match-statistics']")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='a-match-statistics']"))).click()   

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print('{:17} | {:>3} | {:>3} |'.format('name', 'home', 'away'))
print('{:17} | {:>3} | {:>3} |'.format('-'*17, '---', '---'))

# get stats 
for row in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="tab-statistics-0-statistic"]//div[@class="statTextGroup"]'):
    columns = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
    columns = [x.text.strip() for x in columns]
    name = columns[1]
    home = columns[0]
    away = columns[2]
    stats_row[name + ' - home'] = home
    stats_row[name + ' - away'] = away
    print('{:17} | {:>3} | {:>3} |'.format(name, home, away))

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#columns = stats_row.keys()
stats.append(stats_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(stats, columns=stats_row.keys())
df.to_csv('stats.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Very well organized, but there is a way to have it into excel file?

Comment: My idea is to set match details as columns: ball possession, goals attempts etc. Then set soccer ball as columns to have all stats in one row, if there is 1+ goals split in more columns. So will be more simple handle more matches as table

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cI9hR9Y5Ko in this video is showed our my output similar is.

Comment: putting goals in separated columns is not good idea - one match will need only one column, other will need many column, and you would need column with information how many goals you have. And this is why I wrote at the end that now you have to figure out how to organize it in DataFrame (and later save it in excel or csv) because it is not so easy. In normal situation I would keep it in database in two or more tables - one table with base stats - one stat in one row, and in other table I would keep goals but in different way - one goal in one row. But this good for web page but not for stats.

Comment: but if you want to put goals in separated columns then you will have to dynamically add columns when some match will have more goals. And then matches with smaller number of gouls will have empty columns and in these columns you have to put some value which will you inform that there is no goal.

Comment: video show only for stats which are in all matches. They don't try to add goals which may have different number. It need `for`-loop which check if column exists and create new column.

Comment: I added code  which create CSV and it adds all to separated columns.